# The prev variable displays a warning message in groovy, is it normal?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

1.add JSR223Sample
2.add follow values:

```
${__Sms_String_Encrypt(${__groovy(import groovy.json.JsonSlurper ;def respone = prev.getResponseDataAsString();new JsonSlurper().parseText(respone).result,)},${secretKey},2,re)}
```

3.Please allow me to attach a screenshot.
[image]

1. Why is this warning message prompted?
2. Why is it normal to add prev variable references in the script area?For example： prev.getTime().toString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter to it worth reporting it to [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Until it's fixed the options are in:

1. Ignore the warning as the function will still do its job
2. [Decrease JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) by adding the next line *log4j2.xml* file

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy" level="error"/>
   ```

   this way you will stop seeing the message in the jmeter.log file
3. Extract data from the response using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) or [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) and use variables, not the groovy function in the "Parameters" section